# Easiest way to Url Path Encode?

Tags: asp.net

I want to reliably and easily Uri encode paths such as "/folder/foo%bar" to "/folder/foo%25bar".

I would have hoped that `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` would do the trick but this method only escapes spaces.  I don't want to url `HttpUlity.UrlEncode` as this will encode "foo bar" to "foo+bar" - which ain't what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static string CustomURLEncode(string str)
{
       return System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode( str ).Replace(”+”,”%20″);
}
```

Comment: As I said I don't want to use this method because it encodes spaces as '+', which is incorrect

Comment: After checking it looks like the only way to go - if you agree mind removing the downvote :-)